# SQL Insert and Delete query through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am trying send insert and delete sql queries using AJAX and PHP. I have checked the network tab of developer tools and I can see that when I click the input it successfully retrieves the values so the main issue I am having is inserting these values into the DB and deleting values from the DB.

EDIT: No error messages return in regards to my SQL query so I am unsure whats happening.

Here is my HTML and JQUERY code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#favbut").click(function() {
            var username = $("#usernamefav").val();
            var lid = $("#lidfav").val();
            var favourite = $("#favouritefav").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "fave.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    username: username,
                    lid: lid,
                    favourite: favourite
                }
            });
        });
        $("#unfavbut").click(function() {
            var username = $("#usernameunfav").val();
            var lid = $("#lidunfav").val();
            var favourite = $("#favouriteunfav").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "unfave.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    username: username,
                    lid: lid,
                    favourite: favourite
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="usernamefav" value='.$user.'>
<input type="hidden" name="lid" id="lidfav" value='.$lid.'>
<input type="hidden" name="favourite" id="favouritefav" value=YES>
<input class="favButt fav" id="favbut" type="submit" name="faveBTN" value="Fave">';
                
                
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="usernameunfav" value='.$user.'>
<input type="hidden" name="lid" id="lidunfav" value='.$lid.'>
<input type="hidden" name="favourite" id="favouriteunfav" value=YES>
<input class="favButt unfav" id="unfavbut" type="submit" name="unfaveBTN" value="unFave">';
```

Here is the php files:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['favbut'])){
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$lid = $_POST['lid'];
$favourite = $_POST['favourite'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO userslocation (fid,username,lid,favourite) VALUES ('','".$username."', '".$lid."','".$favourite."')";
$result = (mysqli_query($conn, $sql));          
}
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['unfavbut'])){
    include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$lid = $_POST['lid'];
$favourite = $_POST['favourite'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM userslocation WHERE username='$username' AND lid='$lid'";
$result = (mysqli_query($conn, $sql));          
}
?>
```

Any help as to what is going wrong is appreciated!

Comment: You're not checking the results of the query.  What does `mysqli_error($conn)` tell you?

Comment: sorry for the stupid question but where do I read the output of the mysqli_error?

Comment: You can output it wherever you want.  For example, you can just write it directly to the script output:  `echo mysqli_error($conn);`  Then in your client-side code (or in your browser's debugging tools) you'd read the response from the AJAX call.

Comment: I don't know if I am being stupid but it isnt showing anything in the response window it just says "this request has no response available". Sorry for being so hopeless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your queries looks good. But @RonCajan said right about possible SQL Injection.

1) I think you have errors here:

```php
if(isset($_POST['favbut'])) { ...
...
if(isset($_POST['unfavbut'])) { ...
```

You don't pass these values by your $.ajax requests. Add them to your request or instead of passing them you can check isset of `lid` value.

Easy way to check it is to make `echo 1;` before condition and `echo 2;` inside statement block. And watch response.

2) As @RonCajan said if your `fid` column is auto_increment you should skip it in your query, don't set it as `''`.

Also in php if you use double quotes you don't need to use concatenation to insert variables values. [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO userslocation (username, lid, favourite) VALUES ('${username}', '${lid}','${favourite}')";
```

And one more advice. Learn how to use debug tools as [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/). It becomes much easier to find mistakes in your code.

Comment: Although I now have an issue where after making one request, the next one I send wont go through unless I refresh the browser

Comment: It keeps sending the same lid parameter no matter which one is clicked

Comment: It's because you use id selector ```$("#lidfav").val()```. In DOM can be only one element with unique id. It will take first or latest one. 
One way is to use ```data-``` attributes on your buttons. For example ```<input data-lid='.$lid.'... id="unfavbut" />```. In your click handler get value by ```$(this).data('lid')```.
Also it will be better to change ```$("#unfavbut").click(``` to class selector ```$(".favButt.unfav").click(```

Comment: That works to a degree I really am so grateful!!! I just have one last question. At the moment if you favourite a location, you cant then unfavourite it right after without having to refresh. Is that because I have put the data-lid on both?

Comment: Yes. You should update your DOM and attributes after ```fav``` or ```unfav``` action. Change class of button for example to reverse action.

p.s. It's not very polite unmark right answer just because you have more other issues with your code that you didn't asked in first question. 

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

First of all your code is prone to SQL Injection.  Use prepared statement for security purposes. Refer to this site to improve your code. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

I think you have mistaken this one.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userslocation 
(fid,username,lid,favourite) VALUES ('','".$username."', 
'".$lid."','".$favourite."')";
```

Instead use this query :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userslocation 
(username,lid,favourite) VALUES 
('$username','$lid','$favourite')";
```

If your fid has an auto_increment by default you dont need to join it on your query and dont concatenate your query. I think concatenating is for connecting two string or for printing the text.

In your html code. Try to use `<?php echo $variable; ?>` in all your input value. Maybe it does not contain any value.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice and solution, that didn't seem to solve the problem but I will be sure to remember your advice for future coding!

Comment: @RonCajan Your query is invalid. It won't work. 1) you defined 4 columns, but passed only 3 variables. 2) You have syntax error(count single qoutes)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry  I didnt notice it. Ill update the query.

Comment: In principle that should work but it does not seem to be and does not return any kind of error. Im confused as to whats going wrong.

Comment: Try putting condition on your ajax. For example if `if(!username=' '&& !lid=' '&& !favorite==' '){ //ajax code here}

Comment: Try my suggestion.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to solve it as I mentioned to another commenter, after the first time sending each kind of requests every request after sends the same LID parameter. Thanks for your comment though I appreciate your help